# "Could not install from ... as it does not contain a package.json file" when creating react app in windows 10 by npx create-react-app app-name

Tags: reactjs, npm

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316]  
> (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> F:\MERN\ReactJS>npx create-react-app todolist  
> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL  
> npm ERR! Could not install from "saurangpate\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\2372" as it does not contain a package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\om saurangpate\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-12T09_55_38_320Z-debug.log        
> Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1
>
> F:\MERN\ReactJS>
> ```

Comment: What version of npm are you using

Comment: You might want to follow instructions given here https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/640

Comment: 2021-02-12T09_55_38_320Z-debug.log can be useful, please share the relevant part of this file too and add some kind of description of your problem.